# Handle Localized Strings via Enum, Struct, or Other?

Tags: swift, iphone, string, xcode, localization

I'm currently building an app that is going to have Localization. This is a new topic for me and I'm struggling to find an efficient way of handling it. Typically we'd put our strings in Localizable.strings and then anywhere we need to use them we'd use something like `NSLocalized("someKey", comment: "")` however I feel like there's a much better way to do this and to keep them organized, I just don't know what that method is yet. Here's what I've done so far.

#### Localizable.strings

```
"someKey1" = "Hello World";
"someKey2" = "Hello StackOverflow";
```

#### StringConstants.swift

```
enum AlertStrings {
    case ok
    case cancel
}

enum HelloStrings {
    case world
    case stackOverflow

    func getString() -> String {
        var stringValue = ""
        switch self {
            case .world
                stringValue = "someKey1"
            case .stackOverflow:
                stringValue = "someKey2"
        }

        return NSLocalizedString(stringValue, comment: "")
    }
```

Now with this type of setup, I can simply get my strings, without having to remember keys, by doing `HelloStrings.world.getString()` or `HelloStrings.stackOverflow.getString()`. This works, however, there's quite a bit of setup that goes into this for each and every string value that I use. Is there a better way? I'd love to be able to just use something like `HelloStrings.world` but I suspect that's not possible.

Comment: You might want to have a look at SwiftGen: https://github.com/SwiftGen/SwiftGen#strings or R.Swift: https://github.com/mac-cain13/R.swift

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public enum HelloStrings: String {
    case world = "someKey1"
    case stackOverflow = "someKey2"

    var localized: String {
        return NSLocalizedString(self.rawValue, comment: "")
    }
}
```

`HelloStrings.stackOverflow.localized`

If you use SwiftUI :

```
import SwiftUI

public enum HelloStrings: LocalizedStringKey {
    case world = "someKey1"
    case stackOverflow = "someKey2"

    var localized: LocalizedStringKey {
        return rawValue
    }
}
```

`Text(HelloStrings.world.localized)`

Comment: This is concise. I hadn't thought of handling it like this. I think this is the most straightforward answer.

Comment: Nice. I like this. How would I do this with parameters so that my string in strings file could be interpolated? Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

For iOS you would like to use a default `.strings` files with [`NSLocalizedString` macro](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nslocalizedstring).

```
// Localizable.strings (file with your strings)
"welcome_sceen_title" = "Welcome";
"login_button" = "Log in";

// Use in code
NSLocalizedString("welcome_sceen_title", comment: "")
```

Here is a full tutorial:
https://lokalise.com/blog/getting-started-with-ios-localization/

Comment: I understand that portion. I'm trying to eliminate having to constantly use `NSLocalizedString(...)` with every usage. To make it worse keeping track of those String keys is a nightmare in a full production app, without constantly having to reference the `.strings` file.

Comment: you can wrap macro into a string method (see Tip#1 from the tutorial https://lokalise.com/blog/getting-started-with-ios-localization/). And yeah, keeping track of keys is awful :(